# Background jobs stops after a few minutes

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, start-job

See below a simplified version of my PowerShell code.

```
$cred = Import-Clixml d:\cred.xml
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Authentication Credssp -Credential $cred -InDisconnectedSession -SessionOption @{OutputBufferingMode="Drop";IdleTimeout=2147483647} -Scriptblock {
    $start_job = Start-Job -Scriptblock {
        foreach ($user in $list) {
            $a = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $user -Recurse -Force
            Write-Output "$a.Count" | Out-File c:\test.log -Append
    } -ArgumentList $list
}
```

I would send a list of maybe 30 names but after a few minutes of scanning the operations would stop without any error reported, it seems as if the `Start-Job` is blocked or suspended as the `Invoke-Command` is still running.
any idea on how to check or bypass this limitation?

Comment: Fix your code. `$list` is not defined, "$a.count" won't print the count, change it to "$($a.count)". Wrap `Get-ChildItem` in the `@()` array operator, otherwise you might receive `$null` from `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: Also, the `foreach` is missing a closing curly bracket.